# Jotai set callback element returns original state after rendering on react custom modal

Tags: reactjs, typescript, callback, react-functional-component, jotai

i´m trying to create a custom modal using jotai as state manager, i have the following atom in order to receive it from the modal component and listen when it´s visible to open it.

```
import { atom } from "jotai"

type ActionsType = {
  text: string
  onClick: () => void
  element: JSX.Element
}

export type ModalContentType = {
  title: string
  actions: ActionsType[] | []
  children: JSX.Element | null
  visible: boolean
}

export const modalContent = atom<ModalContentType>({
  title: "",
  actions: [],
  children: null,
  visible: false,
})
```

And i have the following modal component with this structure, i listen to the modalContent when it´s visible and set the children, map the actions, clone it with React.cloneElement and set the onClick event passed

```
export default function ModalComponent(): JSX.Element {
  const [modalContent, setModalContent] = useAtom(modalContentAtom)


  // More events and functions

  return (
    <ModalWrapper $visible={modalContent.visible} onClick={closeModal}>
      <ModalContent
        key={modalContent.visible ? "visible" : "hidden"}
        variants={variants}
        initial="hidden"
        animate="enter"
        exit="exit"
        role="dialog"
      >
        <ModalHeader>
          <ModalTitle>{modalContent.title}</ModalTitle>
          <ModalClose onClick={handleCloseModal} id="close-modal" role="button">
            <GrClose />
          </ModalClose>
        </ModalHeader>
        {modalContent.children}
        <ModalFooterWrapper>
          {modalContent.actions.map((action: any) =>
            React.cloneElement(action.element, { ...action.element.props, onClick: action.onClick })
          )}
        </ModalFooterWrapper>
      </ModalContent>
    </ModalWrapper>
  )
}
```

and i open the modal, send the events and children to the useAtom through a callback on an onClick button that i have

```
return (
    <UsersLayout>
      <TableAdmin columns={Object.keys(users[0] || {})} data={users} />
      <Actions>
        <ActionButton
          type="button"
          onClick={() => {
            setModalContent({
              visible: true,
              title: translations.create,
              children: <CreateUserComponent />,
              actions: [
                {
                  text: translations.cancel,
                  onClick: () => setModalContent({ ...modalContent, visible: false }),
                  element: CancelButtonElement,
                },
                {
                  text: translations.create,
                  onClick: handleCreateUser,
                  element: UpdateButtonElement,
                },
              ],
            })
          }}
        >
          Create
        </ActionButton>
       {/* another buttons */}
      </Actions>
    </UsersLayout>
```

handleCreateUser

```
const handleCreateUser = async (): Promise<void> => {
    setLoadingBar(true)
    // await createUserMutation(formCreateData)
    console.log(formCreateData)
    setLoadingBar(false)
  }
```

useEffect used to test if the form changes

```
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log(formCreateData)
  }, [formCreateData])
```

The problem it´s that the handleCreateUser callback only returns the original value of formCreateData (that it´s a state with an object with properties like email, password etc...) returns it´s original value

what the useEffect with the formCreateData dependency log
[image: useEffect console.log]

what log in the callback handleCreateUser
[image]

I tried to use useCallback on the handleCreateUser function, extract the ActionButton to another component and extract the callback of open the modal outside the render, but nothing seems work.

Complete code repository [here](https://github.com/HidenPlus/personal-portfolio/blob/main/app/auth/components/Admin/Users.tsx)

Comment: You didn't show the code that works (useEffect).
Try to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: My bad, i put the repository link on the question.

Comment: You wrote: "what the useEffect with the form dependency log" but the useEffect in the link doesn't print anything...